# ubuntu terminal not found instaed xterm is found

Tags: gnome-terminal

I can not find Ubuntu terminal. I found xterm terminal which is not easy at all.
how can i install terminal. However, I tried to install it via xterm but it told me that no installation candidate. **how to reinstall?**

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you using? If it’s an Ubuntu Desktop release from the past decade, then [Ctrl]+[Alt]+[T] should bring it up (unless you’ve intentionally removed it)

Comment: Maybe the terminal is installed but you don't have a shell. You should try `sudo apt-get install --reinstall bash` and then restart. Terminal should come up with [Ctrl]+[Alt]+[T] as @matigo says.

Answer (score 0):

The terminal is installed by default, even on a minimal install. So check for yourself what happened to your system, because it is not normal not to have the default terminal that comes with the desktop you use.

The command to install the default Ubuntu terminal is

```
sudo apt install gnome-terminal
```

If indeed that says "no installation candidate available" then that is further indication something irregular happened to your system. There is no way for us to guess/know what has happened. It could be improper manipulations as root, it could be hardware failure.

Thus, at this stage, the shortest pain probably will be a fresh install. If that succeeds, watch the system carefully and configure the system correctly using the standard tools. If then, problems re-surge, you can start expecting hardware failure (i.e. failing hard drive, failing hard drive controller, corrupt memory, ...).